# Can a new env in conda inherit specific packages from base environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

When I create conda environments for my projects where I use pytorch,
torch and torchvision packages take along time to install due to slow connection in my region (takes hours sometimes).

Therefore to start working on my projects quickly I don't create a new env, I just use the packages in the base env. I know this will get hairy soon.

That's why I want to know if there is a way to make a new created env inherit specific packages from base env without re-installing.

ps: I understand that conda leverages hard links but I don't understand how to use this in this case. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cloning

The simplest way to use only already installed packages in a new environment is to clone an existing environment (`conda create --clone foo --name bar`). Generally, I don't recommend cloning the **base** environment since it includes Conda and other infrastructure that is only needed in **base**.

At a workflow-level, it might be advantageous to consider creating some template environments which you can clone for different projects.

#### YAML Definitions

However, OP mentions only wanting specific packages. I would still create a new env for this, but start with an existing env using an exported YAML.

```
conda env export -n foo > bar.yaml
```

Edit the `bar.yaml` to remove whatever packages that you don't want (again, if `foo == base`, remove `conda`), then create the new environment with

```
conda env create -f bar.yaml --name bar
```

This will ensure that exactly the packages from the previous environment are used.

Overall, if you using cloning and recreating from YAML files (which include build specifications), then Conda will minimize downloading as well as physical disk usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after reading your answer I think I will use an exported YAML from base env and adjust it to create a new env, but I don't understand what did you mean by " again, if foo == base, remove conda". thanks again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Melai11 sorry for the confusion. That shorthand was meant communicate that if the env you are exporting from (what I called **foo**) happens to be the **base** env, then you'll want to remove the `conda` package from the YAML file. There may be other packages that are unnecessary to keep in the YAML, but I don't have/know of a definitive list.

Comment: Hello there, I've used this solution to export a yaml file from an env (that isn't base), and now I'm planning to export the packages from the base env, and I've found a few packages that start with conda and others that start with Anaconda, and I'm wondering if I should delete all of these packages or just the conda ones? As always, thank you very much.